# ViewModel getting called everytime

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am using LiveData and ViewModel with Firebase. I am using below code to show the data in RecyclerView.

```
public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.toolbar_category)
Toolbar toolbar;
@BindView(R.id.recycler_view_category)
RecyclerView categoryRecyclerView;
private List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
private CategoryAdapter mAdapter;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    context = this;

    mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categoryList, context);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    categoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    categoryRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    categoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);    
    CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CategoryViewModel.class);
    LiveData<DataSnapshot> liveData = categoryViewModel.getDataSnapshotLiveData();
    liveData.observe(this, new Observer<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.e("CategoryActivity","inside");
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotIterable = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot p : dataSnapshotIterable) {
                Category categoryFromFirebase = p.getValue(Category.class);
                categoryList.add(categoryFromFirebase);
            }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
}
```

My problem is that even if I lock the phone and unlock it, everything gets called again and data gets duplicated in the `RecyclerView`. I am not able to understand what's the problem. Please help.

Comment: you need to clear the list

Comment: I want to know why is it getting called every time? @ShivamOberoi

Comment: bcoz you are calling that on OnCreate and its gets called everytime whenever you come to that activity

Comment: But this happens even if the activity is not destroyed. @ShivamOberoi

Comment: can you tell me when onCreate method of an Activity is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear you `arraylist` before add iteam **categoryList.clear();**

```
liveData.observe(this, new Observer<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       categoryList.clear(); //clear your arraylist values before adding

            Log.e("CategoryActivity","inside");
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotIterable = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot p : dataSnapshotIterable) {

                Category categoryFromFirebase = p.getValue(Category.class);

                categoryList.add(categoryFromFirebase);

            }

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can I know why does it get called even when the activity is not destroyed?

Comment: @MehulKanzariya please double check bro..if activity get destroyed it wonot call...maight be you have call some other place...

Answer (score 1):

First understand the scenario:

**Device Lock:** onDestroy(), onCreate(), onStart(), onResume() methods will get called

**Device Unlock:** onResume() method will call

So your logic resides in onCreate() method that's why everything gets called again and again.

To overcome this issue you need to clear your 'categoryList' or initialize it at same place again so as to create new instance of it without any data in it.